# deleting \n with fgetc() saved as an two dimensional array

Tags: c++, function, c++17

im trying to create a file read from an .txt. The `fgetc()` function keeps adding an end of the line \n to every line read from .txt, which messess up the order of reading. Problem is, every character is being saved as an two dimensional char array, so things like `strcspn` wont work. Even so the array has set amount of columns, there still is that pesky `\n`. For example, every time we get to column 128 it supposed to skip to the next row, instead, it goes a notch more. Adding all the `\n` together makes this file have 31 characters more then supposed 32x128=4096. Total amount of characters is 4126, 31 is a sum of all the previouse columns, previouse `\n`. I would like to find a way to read those characters from the .txt separetly, to a presented two-dimensional array, without all the `\n`, to make the total count a multiplication of rows and columns(4096).

```
FILE* plik;
            
    plik = fopen("lvl 1.txt", "r");
     
    int row=32, col=128;

    char pixel_grid[32][128];

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            pixel_grid[i][j] = fgetc(plik);                    
            cout << pixel_grid[i][j];
        }
    }fclose(plik);
```

I'll be greatful for your help.

As said, I've tried things like this: `pixel_grid[32][128][strcspn(pixel_grid[32][128], "\n")] = 0;`

Error messege recieved: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: It isn't "adding" it; it is reading it from the file.

Comment: What does it mean to save a *character* as a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Can you *guarantee* that the newlines (`\n`) will always and only occur at the end of each line of 128 characters? If so, just add an extra `int skip = fgetc(plik);` line after the inner `for` loop?

Comment: ... and even then, if (perchance) some are missing, you can put the character back: `if (skip != '\n') ungetc(skip, plik);` ... maybe?

Comment: You could always `pixel_grid[i][j] = fgetc(plik); if (pixel_grid[i][j]=='\n') { j--; continue; } cout << pixel_grid[i][j];` if you want to ignore the newlines.